# What are the known implications of “There exists a Berkeley cardinal”?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Inspired by this question: [What are the known implications of "There exists a Reinhardt cardinal" in the theory "ZF + j"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87222/what-are-the-known-implications-of-there-exists-a-reinhardt-cardinal-in-the-th)

**Definitions:**

> $\delta$ is Berkeley iff for every $\alpha\lt\delta$ and transitive set $M$ such that $\delta\in M$, there is some $j: M\prec M$ such that $\alpha\lt\text{crit}j\lt\delta$.

> $\delta$ is club Berkeley iff for every club $C\subseteq\delta$ and transitive set $M$ such that $\delta\in M$, there is some $j: M\prec M$ such that $\text{crit}j\in C$.

> $\delta$ is limit club Berkeley if $\delta$ is club Berkeley and a limit of Berkeley cardinals.

**Question 1: What is the progress on anaylizing Berkeley cardinals?**

> Have any of the major open problems since the introduction of Berkeley cardinals been solved? Are club Berkeley cardinals larger than Berkeley cardinals? What is the effect of increasing levels of Choice on Berkeley cardinals?

Berkeley cardinals are infamously large large cardinals. The original paper *Large Cardinals Beyond Choice* where they were introduced, left open 7 problems, 4 of which were related to Berkeley cardinals. Have any of these been solved? Have any new techniques or results created hope that they might be solved in the foreseeable future?

**Question 2: Can we go bigger?**

> Are there any large cardinals that imply the consistency of (Limit club) Berkeley cardinals? If they exist, are there any interesting results that these larger cardinals imply.

This question is simple. How big can we go? For this particular question, I am willing to accept more "off-the-cuff" answers. Large cardinals developed in private communications, or even developed specifically to answer this question. All the criteria are is that they have to be stronger than club Berkeley cardinals, they can't be trivial extensions, they can't be obvious, and they have to either have clear reasoning behind their development, or at least you need to be able to do something interesting with them.

**Question 3: Can we rescue Berkeley cardinals?**

> Are there any variants of Berkeley cardinals that can survive even in the context of Woodin's Weak $HOD$ conjecture?

Consider the nightmare scenario: Over the next decade or two, more and more results related to Reinhardt and Berkeley cardinals are proved, the open problems are resolved, and an interesting structural theory is developed. Than the weak $HOD$ conjecture is proved and that entire hierarchy is wiped out.

It is really this nightmare scenario that is the motivation for my question. Is there any weakening of Berkeley cardinals that would allow us to save any structure theory developed, in much the same way as set theory was rescued after Russel's paradox? The obvious answer might be the $HOD$-variants, but I believe even these can be wiped out. Assuming that is not the case, the question is do these really have all the properties that Berkeley cardinals have.

For example:

> Are $HOD$-Super Reinhardt cardinals stronger than $HOD$-Reinhardt cardinals?

Better yet, perhaps some of the open problems that cannot be solved with classical Berkeley cardinals, can be resolved with these new ones!

Comment: Would the downvoter like to explain the problem they had with the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I had to guess, you're asking 6 questions. I suppose some people find that off-putting. (You know, like someone who stands up after a talk and rattles off a series of questions.)

Comment: I see. I meant those questions as example questions, but I can see how it would be off putting.

Comment: I should add to what @Andrej wrote that these questions are kind of loaded as well. Nobody interacted with large cardinals beyond choice for a long time (in part, I suspect, since for over two decades Woodin hinted that his refutation is almost ready), and so a lot of these questions remain open and unstudied. Asking open questions on MathOverflow always felt to me as an exercise in futility.

Comment: In a way, that answers the first question. I have not seen any papers in a long time addressing Berkeley cardinals, however that didn't mean that don't exist, and I wanted to be sure. However, neither question 2 or question 3 are requests for solutions of open problems. Do you have any ideas for 2 or 3?

Comment: An open question is not necessarily of the form "Does CH follow from ZFC" or "Can we prove that V=L". Open questions can also be of the form "What can we say about X" or "How can we generalise Y", especially when X and Y are topics that were not well-studied. These are questions for a research proposal, not MathOverflow. These are good questions with which to end a talk about Berkeley cardinals. Yes, MO plays a half-role with these sort of questions, but at some point one has to ask whether or not they are overdoing it.

Comment: I see. I assumed that a question of the form "How much do we know about X" would be legitimate. It is a tragedy that so little effort has been put into studying Reinhardt and Berkeley cardinals. I think I will still leave these questions up on the off-chance that someone does actually have an answer (Perhaps for question 2?).

Comment: From your comments, I gather that Woodin's paper together with the paper on $L(V_{\delta+1})$ are the only references for Berkeley cardinals in the entire literature. I assumed so, but I didn't know for sure. Is that accurate?

Comment: Other than "Large cardinals beyond choice", there are Cutolo's papers "Berkeley cardinals and the structure of $L(V_{\delta+1})$" (JSL) (is that what you're referring to in the comment above?) and "The cofinality of the least Berkeley cardinal and the extent of dependent choice" (MLQ). There's also "Choiceless large cardinals and set-theoretic potentialism" by Cutolo and Hamkins (preprint on arXiv).

Comment: And more generally, $N$-Berkeley cardinals appear in Cutolo's paper "$N$-Berkeley cardinals and weak extender models" (to appear in JSL). There's also an old fact on "rank-Berkeley" cardinals mentioned in the last section of Goldberg's and my paper "Periodicity in the cumulative hierarchy" (preprint on arXiv).

Comment: Thank you very much for the references!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: About question 2: mathoverflow.net/questions/320078/what-is-the-consistency-strength-of-this-kind-of-iterating-berkeley-cardinals.
Even cofinality least berkeley is open problem and may be realated to sequence of large cardinal axioms (and weak axioms of choice)
(Large cardinals beyond choice, remark 6.4)

Comment: What current status of this hypotesis (about of consistency relation) ?

Comment: Consider the nightmare scenario: Foreman's maximality principle is true...